# iPhone download images and display correct ratio

Tags: iphone, image

I'm downloading a bunch of images from a server and displaying them on the screen. I have about 320x450 to work with. Each image size has a different size, how do i correctly resize images so that they fit on the iphone screen and retain the correct ratio and the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `UIImageView`s of whatever size you can fit and set them to scale with contentMode:

```
myUIImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
imageview.frame=CGRectMake(x,y,img.size.width,img.size.height);
[self.view addSubView imageview];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that, adapting to your image file type :

```
UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] _imageScaledToSize:CGSizeMake(32.0f, 32.0f) interpolationQuality:1];
```

Comment: "3.3.1 Applications may only use Documented APIs in the manner prescribed by Apple and must not use or call any private APIs." 
The non-public API that is included in your application is _imageScaledToSize:interpolationQuality:…"